# Regular expression for validating user input

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a Java program and try to get an `int[]` from a string like `1,2,5,2,11`.

But first I need to judge if the user put the right format, like "," + numbers. How can I write this as a Java regular expression?

```
//set the default value of int[] a;
        int[] a  = {2,3,1,-2,2,7};  
        //set the UI;
        String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter the array to be checked: ");
        String[] strs = text.split(",");
        System.out.println(strs);
        System.out.println(strs.length);
        int[] a2 = new int[strs.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++){
            a2[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
        }
```

Hey guys, sorry about not making it clear first time, I want the user to enter the format like "," + any positive or negative digit, and can be space tolerated, just like
"1, -2, 1,3,+55"

Comment: what is the right format in your case?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. For the future, please visit [ask] (again?), and read the part about doing research before asking a question. It shouldn't be hard to find documentation about how to write a regular expression in Java. It'd be helpful to show what you've already attempted and where, specifically you got stuck.

Comment: Hi all! Thank you for replying so quick, below is where I am currently:

Comment: String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter the array to be checked: ");
String[] strs = text.split(",");

Comment: Nooooooo, don't post code in comments. Use [[edit]] option to add it to question.

Comment: Just to look for a way to make it robust, for example, some users will enter like"#,3@2,123"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To validate your input you can use something like

```
if (text.matches("-?\\d+(,\\s?-?\\d+)*")){
    //try to split
}else{
    //inform user about wrong data format
}
```

- `-?` means that minus is optional
- `\\d+` means one or more digit,
- `,\\s?-?\\d+` means "comma", "white space" (one or none), "minus sign" (one or none), "digit" (one or more),
- `(,\\s?-?\\d+)*` means that this structure can appear zero or more times.

Comment: `"\\d+(,\\d+)*"` would allow `123,4,5,67890`.

Comment: @MattBall Yes since OP used `1,2,5,2,11` I assumed that number is one or more than one digit. Is there something wrong with it? Am I missing something?

Comment: I inferred that the commas were meant to delimit separate numbers.

Comment: cool! it works! how about allow space between number and ,?

Comment: like "1, 12, 2,3,   12"

Comment: also, user can put "-" as a negative, so how to do that?

Comment: @user2101218 add \\s to allow spaces, you can add `?` to make it optional

Comment: text.matches("\\d+(,?\\s\\d+)*" like that?

Comment: Thank you Pshemo! that's an correct and awesome one!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regex at all for this, just [`String#split(",")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Integer#parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Regex alone doesn't suffice to turn strings into numbers, anyway.

Comment: The OP wanted to validate the user input using the regular expression first.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, but `Integer#parseInt()` is the right choice, not regex.

Comment: "I got 99 problems, so I used regex... now I have 100 problems."

Comment: It is also good to preprocess input by replacing all spaces before splitting and parse integer.

Comment: what if the user put like "5%6~1212,as12", the program will run a exception

Comment: @user2101218 is that a question or a statement? What do you want the output to be with rubbish input like that? You have not adequately explained what input you expect to be handled (and how) and what input you expect to be rejected.

Comment: The user wanted to accept input that matches the format they already mentioned in the first revision of  their question, and reject input that doesn't match this format. I believe that part was quite clear. Of course if users can input anything, you can assume they enter "rubbish". That's the whole point of validating user input.